# Only one of my array adapters will work at a time in my row

Tags: java, android, textview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I have two textfields in my row, and I'm using array adapters to assign their text. However, only one of them will work at a time. If I comment one out, then the other will work, and vice versa. What am I doing wrong here and how can I make it work properly?

```
private void getFiles() {
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    times = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();

    File f = new File(getString(R.string.file_path));
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)  {
        File file = files[i];

        path.add(file.getPath());
        names.add(file.getName());
        CharSequence relativeTime = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(file.lastModified());
        times.add((String) relativeTime);
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> messageSenders = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.message_name, names);
    ArrayAdapter<String> messageTimes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.message_time, times);

    setListAdapter(messageSenders);
    setListAdapter(messageTimes);
}
```

Comment: Well, obviously, you're calling `setListAdapter` twice. Second call will overwrite the first adapter. You need to create an object which would hold both `path` and `name` for one line and then use it in adapter.

Comment: Ah, okay I got you. Thanks